# Linq query (could not be translated)

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I have very simple Linq query that shows error on run time

**the query is**

```
        // string[] Blocks = _TableView.permission.BlockList.Split(',');
        // string[] Permissions = _TableView.permission.PermissionsList.Split(',');
        string[] Blocks = ... some string array ...;
        string[] Permissions = ... some string array ... ;
            var test = await (from t in _context.DocumentIn
                                          where 
                                          Permissions.Contains(t.Imp_Exp.ToString()) &&
                                          Permissions.Contains(t.confLevel.ToString()) &&
                                          Blocks.Contains(t.BlockName)
                                          select t).ToListAsync();
```

**the error is**

```
could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, 
or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),
AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

**some notes**
when I trace I find Blocks and Permissions full of values.
when I remove from the query two conditions of Permissions it works like the following

```
            var test = await (from t in _context.DocumentIn
                                          where 
                                          /*Permissions.Contains(t.Imp_Exp.ToString()) &&
                                          Permissions.Contains(t.confLevel.ToString()) &&*/
                                          Blocks.Contains(t.BlockName)
                                          select t).ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Are `t.Imp_Exp` and `t.confLevel` integer properties?

Comment: @octavioccl yes they are. and thank you so much for your answer.

Comment: you're welcome, glad I could help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case `Permissions` is an array of string based on integers, an easy solution is to cast the array to `int`:

```
int[] Permissions = _TableView.permission
                              .PermissionsList
                              .Split(',')
                              .Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
```

And remove the `ToString` call which are that are causing the exception:

```
  var test = await (from t in _context.DocumentIn
                    where Permissions.Contains(t.Imp_Exp) &&
                          Permissions.Contains(t.confLevel) &&
                          Blocks.Contains(t.BlockName)
                    select t).ToListAsync();
```

But the main idea is that, removing the `ToString` call, whatever is your scenario, you should try to remove them from your query